# Colour line according to row value with plotly graph objects

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I have a dataframe as below:

```
to_plot = pd.DataFrame({
'date_time':
['2022-09-20 14:10:50',
 '2023-11-30 15:04:14',
 '2023-04-28 15:05:44',
 '2023-06-30 15:51:31',
 '2023-07-14 15:53:39',
 '2022-11-11 16:03:10',
 '2023-07-04 16:19:20',
 '2023-06-20 16:09:59',
 '2023-06-13 16:04:28',
 '2022-11-15 13:55:48',
 '2022-11-01 14:34:42',
 '2023-11-28 16:08:04',
 '2023-06-02 16:32:39',
 '2023-08-04 16:01:21',
 '2023-12-06 14:08:20',
 '2023-06-27 16:01:41',
 '2023-05-16 15:59:41',
 '2022-09-09 15:28:06',
 '2023-06-07 15:59:13',
 '2022-11-08 14:02:57'],
'attribute':
['0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.110',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.110',
 '0.110',
 '0.110',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.110',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.575',
 '0.110'],
'side':
['left',
 'right',
 'left',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'right',
 'left',
 'right',
 'right'],
'amount':
['40.0',
 '352.0',
 '123.0',
 '82.0',
 '174.0',
 '785.0',
 '161.0',
 '142.0',
 '24.0',
 '563.0',
 '178.0',
 '481.0',
 '23.0',
 '127.0',
 '480.0',
 '211.0',
 '83.0',
 '56.0',
 '110.0',
 '170.0'],
'percent':
['23.0',
 '40.0',
 '25.0',
 '23.0',
 '33.0',
 '56.0',
 '30.0',
 '34.0',
 '26.0',
 '61.0',
 '56.0',
 '62.0',
 '26.0',
 '34.0',
 '69.0',
 '34.0',
 '22.0',
 '23.0',
 '27.0',
 '51.0']})
```

now I would like to use plotly graph objects to plot the percentage column of each attribute & side column along the x axis (which should be column date_time). I would like to colour the lines with a colour that goes towards purple if the row value in column amount is high and a colour that goes towards blue if the amount value is low.

I have the code below but no matter how I change it I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'pandas.core.series.Series' received for the 'color' property of scatter.line
        Received value: date_time
2022-11-11 16:03:10    purple
2022-11-15 13:55:48       red
2022-11-01 14:34:42     green
2023-11-28 16:08:04    orange
2023-12-06 14:08:20    orange
2022-11-08 14:02:57     green
Name: color, dtype: category
Categories (6, object): ['blue' < 'green' < 'yellow' < 'orange' < 'red' < 'purple']

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, etc
```

I don't know what else I can change about the below code?

```
to_plot = to_plot.assign(date_time=pd.to_datetime(to_plot.date_time),
                         amount=to_plot.amount.astype(float))

to_plot = to_plot.set_index('date_time')

# Define bins for 'amount' values
bins = np.linspace(int(to_plot.amount.min()), int(to_plot.amount.max())+1, 7)
labels = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple']

# Map 'amount' values to the color bins
to_plot['color'] = pd.cut(to_plot['amount'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

fig = go.Figure()

attribute_direction_groups = to_plot.groupby(['attribute', 'side'])

for name, group in attribute_direction_groups:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=group.index,
        y=group['percent'],
        mode='lines+markers',
        line=dict(color=group['color']),
        name=' '.join(name),
        hovertext=group['amount']  # Display 'sec' value on hover
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Percentage Over Time for Speed and Direction Groups',
    xaxis_title='Index',
    yaxis_title='Percentage'
)

fig.plot()
```

I don't care about the exact colours of the lines it should just reflect the value of column amount somehow. So it can also just be the opacity of the line.

Comment: I just cannot pass neither a list nor an array nor a series nor anything except a simple string to color (in line)